# step_dummy output is not recognised in r vetiver's api

Tags: r, tidymodels, recipe, vetiver

I'm using several steps of data pre-processing in below ml workflow to use the final model in the production via vetiver api.

The workflow and prediction work well in my local environment, however I get an error when trying to run an example in vetiver api.
When  keep_original_cols = FALSE in step_dummy the error message says that original columns are not present in the data . I tried keep_original_cols = TRUE,  but in that case the error message output relates to format of the original columns (see example below).

Below is example from https://juliasilge.com/blog/sf-trees-random-tuning/

```
sf_trees <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-28/sf_trees.csv")

trees_df <- sf_trees %>%
 mutate(
   legal_status = case_when(
     legal_status == "DPW Maintained" ~ legal_status,
     TRUE ~ "Other"
   ),
   plot_size = parse_number(plot_size)
 ) %>%
 select(-address) %>%
 na.omit() %>%
 mutate_if(is.character, factor)

set.seed(123)
trees_split <- initial_split(trees_df, strata = legal_status)
trees_train <- training(trees_split)
trees_test <- testing(trees_split)
tree_rec <- recipe(legal_status ~ ., data = trees_train) %>%
 update_role(tree_id, new_role = "ID") %>%
 step_other(species, caretaker, threshold = 0.01) %>%
 step_other(site_info, threshold = 0.005) %>%
 step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), keep_original_cols = T) %>%
 step_date(date, features = c("month","year")) %>%
 step_downsample(legal_status)

tree_prep <- prep(tree_rec) 
juiced <- juice(tree_prep)  

tune_spec <- rand_forest(
   mtry = tune(),
   trees = 1000,
   min_n = tune()
 ) %>%
 set_mode("classification") %>%
 set_engine("ranger")

tune_wf <- workflow() %>%
 add_recipe(tree_rec) %>%
 add_model(tune_spec)

set.seed(234)
trees_folds <- vfold_cv(trees_train)
doParallel::registerDoParallel()

set.seed(345)
tune_res <- tune_grid(
 tune_wf,
 resamples = trees_folds,
 grid = 20
)

rf_grid <- grid_regular(
 mtry(range = c(10, 30)),
 min_n(range = c(2, 8)),
 levels = 5
)

set.seed(456)
regular_res <- tune_grid(
 tune_wf,
 resamples = trees_folds,
 grid = rf_grid
)

best_auc <- select_best(regular_res, "roc_auc")

final_rf <- finalize_model(
 tune_spec,
 best_auc
)

final_rf
final_wf <- workflow() %>%
 add_recipe(tree_rec) %>%
 add_model(final_rf)

final_res <- final_wf %>%
 fit(data=trees_train)

# Creating board
model_board <- board_temp()
# Model versioning
rf_ptype <- extract_recipe(final_res) %>% 
 bake(new_data = trees_df, -all_outcomes()) %>% 
 vctrs::vec_ptype()
RF_mod <- vetiver_model(final_res, "RF_fit", save_ptype = rf_ptype)  
model_board %>% vetiver_pin_write(RF_mod)
model_board %>% pin_meta(RF_mod)
```

Creating model API

```
pr() %>% vetiver_api(RF_mod) %>%
  pr_run(port = 8088)

endpoint <- vetiver_endpoint("https://127.0.0.1:8088/predict")
endpoint
```

The example input is :

```
[
  {
    "tree_id": 53227,
    "species": "Celtis sinensis :: Chinese Hackberry",
    "site_order": 6,
    "site_info": "Sidewalk: Curb side : Cutout",
    "caretaker": "SFUSD",
    "date": "2005-03-12",
    "dbh": 3,
    "plot_size": 3,
    "latitude": 37.73225,
    "longitude": -122.3934,
    "species_Eriobotrya.deflexa....Bronze.Loquat": 0,
    "species_Ginkgo.biloba....Maidenhair.Tree": 0,
    "species_Lagunaria.patersonii....Primrose.Tree": 0,
    "species_Lophostemon.confertus....Brisbane.Box": 0,
    "species_Magnolia.grandiflora..Little.Gem.....Little.Gem.Magnolia": 0,
    "species_Magnolia.grandiflora..Samuel.Sommer.....Samuel.Sommer.Magnolia": 0.5,
    "species_Magnolia.grandiflora....Southern.Magnolia": 0,
    "species_Maytenus.boaria....Mayten": 0,
    "species_Melaleuca.quinquenervia....Cajeput": 0,
    "species_Metrosideros.excelsa....New.Zealand.Xmas.Tree": 0,
    "species_Olea.europaea....Olive.Tree": 0,
    "species_Pittosporum.undulatum....Victorian.Box": 0,
    "species_Platanus.x.hispanica....Sycamore..London.Plane": 0,
    "species_Prunus.cerasifera....Cherry.Plum": 0,
    "species_Prunus.serrulata..Kwanzan.....Kwanzan.Flowering.Cherry": 0,
    "species_Prunus.serrulata....Ornamental.Cherry": 0,
    "species_Pyrus.calleryana....Ornamental.Pear": 0,
    "species_Pyrus.kawakamii....Evergreen.Pear": 0,
    "species_Tree.s....": 0,
    "species_Tristania.conferta...": 0,
    "species_Tristaniopsis.laurina..Elegant.....Small.leaf.Tristania..Elegant.": 0,
    "species_Tristaniopsis.laurina....Swamp.Myrtle": 0,
    "species_Ulmus.parvifolia....Chinese.Elm": 0,
    "species_Washingtonia.robusta....Mexican.Fan.Palm": 0,
    "species_other": 0,
    "site_info_Sidewalk..Curb.side...Cutout": 1,
    "site_info_Sidewalk..Curb.side...Yard": 0,
    "site_info_Sidewalk..Property.side...Cutout": 0,
    "site_info_other": 0,
    "caretaker_Port": 0,
    "caretaker_Private": 0,
    "caretaker_SFUSD": 1,
    "caretaker_other": 0,
    "date_month": "Mar",
    "date_year": 2005
 }
]
```

The error message I get:

```
{
  "error": "500 - Internal server error",
  "message": "\u001b[1m\u001b[33mError\u001b[39m in `warn_to_error()`:\u001b[22m\n\u001b[33m!\u001b[39m [0, 2]: expected value in level set, but got 'Celtis sinensis :: Chinese Hackberry'\n"
}
```

I've also tried manually change the input in vetiver example to have right formatting but got:

```
{
 "error": "500 - Internal server error",
 "message": "\u001b[1m\u001b[33mError\u001b[39m in `warn_to_error()`:\u001b[22m\n\u001b[33m!\u001b[39m [0, 2]: expected value in level set, but got '1'\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important thing to learn here is that when you deploy a tidymodels workflow, you deploy both the preprocessing recipe and the random forest estimator *together*. This means that the input data prototype involves the variables in its initial formatting, not the intermediate formatting after the recipe is applied. Take a look at implementing a model API in this way:

```r
## train a model:
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(themis)
sf_trees <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-28/sf_trees.csv")
#> Rows: 192987 Columns: 12
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (6): legal_status, species, address, site_info, caretaker, plot_size
#> dbl  (5): tree_id, site_order, dbh, latitude, longitude
#> date (1): date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

trees_df <- sf_trees %>%
    mutate(
        legal_status = case_when(
            legal_status == "DPW Maintained" ~ legal_status,
            TRUE ~ "Other"
        ),
        plot_size = parse_number(plot_size)
    ) %>%
    select(-address) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, factor)
#> Warning: 109 parsing failures.
#>   row col expected actual
#> 10979  -- a number    TR 
#> 13245  -- a number    CUT
#> 13495  -- a number    TR 
#> 13501  -- a number    TR 
#> 13502  -- a number    TR 
#> ..... ... ........ ......
#> See problems(...) for more details.

set.seed(123)
trees_split <- initial_split(trees_df, strata = legal_status)
trees_train <- training(trees_split)
trees_test <- testing(trees_split)
tree_rec <- recipe(legal_status ~ ., data = trees_train) %>%
    update_role(tree_id, new_role = "ID") %>%
    step_other(species, caretaker, threshold = 0.01) %>%
    step_other(site_info, threshold = 0.005) %>%
    step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), keep_original_cols = T) %>%
    step_date(date, features = c("month","year")) %>%
    step_downsample(legal_status)


rf_spec <- rand_forest(trees = 1e3, mode = "classification")


final_fit <- workflow(tree_rec, rf_spec) %>% fit(data = trees_train)
```

Now we can build the vetiver deployable model object, and version it. Notice that we don't need to provide our own input data prototype; it can be read automatically off the tidymodels workflow:

```r
## version the model:
library(pins)
library(vetiver)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vetiver'
#> 
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tune':
#> 
#>     load_pkgs
model_board <- board_temp()
v <- vetiver_model(final_fit, "RF-fit")  
model_board %>% vetiver_pin_write(v)
#> Creating new version '20221212T182406Z-cc5f5'
#> Writing to pin 'RF-fit'
#> 
#> Create a Model Card for your published model
#> • Model Cards provide a framework for transparent, responsible reporting
#> • Use the vetiver `.Rmd` template as a place to start
model_board %>% pin_meta("RF-fit")
#> List of 12
#>  $ file       : chr "RF-fit.rds"
#>  $ file_size  : 'fs_bytes' int 11.8M
#>  $ pin_hash   : chr "cc5f56b86e7184ec"
#>  $ type       : chr "rds"
#>  $ title      : chr "RF-fit: a pinned list"
#>  $ description: chr "A ranger classification modeling workflow"
#>  $ tags       : NULL
#>  $ created    : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2022-12-12 11:24:06"
#>  $ api_version: num 1
#>  $ user       : list()
#>  $ name       : chr "RF-fit"
#>  $ local      :List of 3
#>   ..$ dir    : 'fs_path' chr "/var/folders/hv/hzsmmyk9393_m7q3nscx1slc0000gn/T/RtmpXM1fFS/pins-ebb03322c3e4/RF-fit/20221212T182406Z-cc5f5"
#>   ..$ url    : NULL
#>   ..$ version: chr "20221212T182406Z-cc5f5"
```

And then we can use that to set up an API:

```r
## set up model API:
library(plumber)
pr() %>% 
    vetiver_api(v) ## next pipe to pr_run(port = 8088)
#> # Plumber router with 2 endpoints, 4 filters, and 1 sub-router.
#> # Use `pr_run()` on this object to start the API.
#> ├──[queryString]
#> ├──[body]
#> ├──[cookieParser]
#> ├──[sharedSecret]
#> ├──/logo
#> │  │ # Plumber static router serving from directory: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/vetiver
#> ├──/ping (GET)
#> └──/predict (POST)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here is what the interactive visual documentation for the API looks like:

[image: vetiver rapidoc interface]

Notice that the `species` variable is still in its string (factor in R) formatting, not dummy variables.

If for some reason, you *do* need to provide a custom input data prototype, you would use `vctrs::vec_ptype(trees_train)`, because that is the input data for the workflow (not the output of the recipe).